# How to make directive react to change of value on the parent scope? angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a directive, where it observe the 'playerSearchSpinnerOn' property in the parent scope. where the value changes, than execute code in my directive link function. At the moment, my observe function isn't been triggered when value changes.

html

```
  <div id="addUsers" class="center" spinner spinnerOn="{{playerSearchSpinnerOn}}">
```

directive

```
 monopolyMenuModule.directive('spinner', function () {
    return {

        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            attr.observe('spinnerOn', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                var spinner = new spinner();
                if (newValue) {
                    // load spinner
                    spinner.spin(elem);
                }
                else if (newValue == false) {
                    // close spinner
                    spinner(false);
                }
            });


        }
    }
```

parent controller

```
 monopolyMenuModule.controller('AddUsersCtrl', ['$scope', 'addUserServices', 'GameGroupDetails', function ($scope, service, GameGroupDetails) {

     // add code to call notifyUsers object.. watch pluralsight "connecting our server to client" and "how signalr works"
     $scope.playerSearchSpinnerOn = false;

     $scope.FindUsers = function () {
         if (GameGroupDetails != null) {
             service.FindUsers(GameGroupDetails).done(function () {
                 // add spinner once group has been show in invite screen
                 $scope.playerSearchSpinnerOn = true;
             });
         }
     };

 }])
```

when playerSearchSpinnerOn property changes in the AddUserCtrl parent controller, i want my 'spinner' directive to react to this change.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: it should be `attr.$observe` then all code will started working

Answer (score 5):

Instead of watching an attribute, you should instead use an **isolated scope**

```
monopolyMenuModule.directive('spinner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
          spinnerOn: "@"
        }
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            $scope.$watch('spinnerOn', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                var spinner = new spinner();
                if (newValue) {
                    // load spinner
                    spinner.spin(elem);
                }
                else if (newValue == false) {
                    // close spinner
                    spinner(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This way you don't have to rely on any weird parent-based logic, you just pass in the value you want to watch. That being said, I have no idea what this `spinner` thing is, and I suspect you have some issues there.

Also, read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope) blog for a great guide on isolated scopes.

Comment: Also see Sitepoint's article on AngularJS directives. observe is overbloated for this simple case.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I had to wrap the playerSearchSpinnerOn property  with the $apply service. This was needed because, changing this property was happening outside of angular' knowledge. calling apply() looks for any new changes in the model, and if one or more is found, then it update's the DOM.

```
     $scope.FindUsers = function () {
         if (GameGroupDetails != null) {
             service.FindUsers(GameGroupDetails).done(function () {
                 // add spinner once group has been show in invite screen

                 // apply is needed and apply is only called in angularjs directives
                 $scope.$apply(function(){ 
                        $scope.playerSearchSpinnerOn = true;
                 });


             });
         }
     };
```

Comment: why `$apply()` needed here?

Comment: In my case, $apply() was needed because nothing had happened that would trigger the watchers (admittedly, my case is significantly different from OP, but the same solution applied).

Answer (score 1):

You made some sort of typo, it should be `attr.$observe` instead of `attr.observe`, $observe will work as like watch inside a directive, it will call a `attr.$observe` function whenever the interpolation (`{{}}`) directive of attribute gets evaluated. Also on UI use attribute as hyphen (`-`) separated & in directive it would be used as camelCase instead of

**HTML**

```
<div id="addUsers" class="center" spinner spinner-on="{{playerSearchSpinnerOn}}">
```

**Directive**

```
monopolyMenuModule.directive('spinner', function () {
  return {

    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
        attr.$observe('spinnerOn', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var spinner = new spinner();
            if (newValue) {
                // load spinner
                spinner.spin(elem);
            }
            else if (newValue == false) {
                // close spinner
                spinner(false);
            }
        });


    }
 }
```

Comment: I made the change, but $observe callback function still not being triggered

Comment: Still no luck.  I'm using angular.module.config, which loads the html view template(referencing the spinner direcitve , using  the AddUsersCtrl controller) after the compilation of the spinner directive js script.... Is this a problem?

Comment: could you please share you config code? Also did you change `spinnerOn` to `sinner-on` in you directive element?